# Need some advice implementing stacks in hanoi

Tags: c++, class, recursion, struct

I have some doubts on how to implement stacks in a Hanoi game in C++, I understand how Hanoi and stacks works but I don't quite understand how to link them.

Each peg is an array of numbers but I don't get how to move them from one to another in the correct order.

What I'm trying to do is to use each peg as an stack(array) of numbers, moving their disks using POP and  PUSH.

Maybe something like, PUSH(Destination, POP(Source)) or Destination.PUSH(POP.AUX())

Where

First peg = Source, Second peg = Destination, Third peg = Aux

## main.cpp

```
 # include < iostream >

 # include " HanoiLib.h " // Recursive Hanoi method

 # include " LibPila.h " // My stack lib


using namespace std;
using namespace PILA;

int main()
{
    Pila P1; // From LibPila.h class Pila
    int Dsk;

Dsk = P1.getData(); // Get the number of disks

for(int i = 0; i < Dsk; i++)
{

    P1.PUSH(P1.POP()); // Fill the first peg

}

P1.Print(); // Print the disks

    Tower(Dsk, 1, 3, 2); // Where 1, 2 and 3 are the pegs
    P1.PUSH(P1.POP()); // This is a wrong idea of how to move the disks..
    Tower(Dsk, 3, 1, 2);

return 0;
}
```

## HanoiLib.h

```
 # ifndef _LibHanoi_H_

 # define _LibHanoi_H_

using namespace std;

        void Tower(int Dsk, int Src, int Dst, int aux)
        {
        if(Dsk > 0)
        {
            Tower(Dsk - 1, Src, Dst, aux);
            cout << "Move disk " << Dsk << "from " << Src << "to " << aux << endl;
            Tower(Dsk - 1, Dst, aux, Src);

        }
    }
# endif // __LibHanoi_H_
```

## LibPila.h

```
 # ifndef _LibPila_H_
 # define _LibPila_H_

 # define MAX_STACK 10 // Max size of the stack

using namespace std;
namespace PILA

{

class Pila
{

private:

    int stack[MAX_STACK]; // MAX_STACK = 10
    int top = -1; // The top of the stack

public:

void PUSH(int val)
{

    if(top == MAX_STACK -1 )
        cout << "Stack overflow!!" << endl;

    stack[++top] = val;

}

int POP()
{

if(top == -1)
    cout << "There's nothing here!!" << endl;

top--;

return top;

}

int Top()
{
    return stack[top];
}

void Print()
{
     int i;

     cout << "Stack: ";
     for(i = 0; i <= top; i++)
        cout << stack[i];
    cout << "" << endl;
 } 

int getData()
{
    int x;

     cout << "Insert NO of disks: "<< endl;
    cin >> x;

     return x;
 }

};

}
# endif // __LibPila_H_
```

Comment: Sorry but where is the error?

Comment: No idea what the ask is here.

Comment: There are no errors, just I'm asking about the implementation of the stacks in Hanoi, that's my doubt